# Laravel: не передается параметр в функцию замыкания группы маршрутов

Tags: laravel, аргументы

Начинаю делать многоязычный сайт. Язык решил обрабатывать как префикс в маршрутизации. В моем случае \routes\web.php выглядит так:

```
$languages = [null, 'ua', 'ru', 'en'];
foreach($languages as $language)
{
    Route::prefix($language)->group(function($language)
    {
        //dd($language);
        App::setlocale($language);
        Auth::routes();
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    });
}
```

Но функция App::setlocale() поучает в качестве аргумента объект класса Illuminate\Routing\Router вместо строки. В этом можно убедится раскоментировав dd($language);

Comment: На уровне мидлваров это надо делать

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы самостоятельно находить ответы на вопросы типа "почему функция App::setlocale() поучает в качестве аргумента объект класса Illuminate\Routing\Router вместо строки?", надо научиться не доверять своим ожиданиям насчёт работы кода, а проверять как на самом деле код работает.

Давайте попробуем. Почему колбэк group должен принять аргумент $language? Обещано ли такое в документации Laravel? Что на самом деле происходит внутри функции `group`? В документации фрэймворка сказано, что группа позволяет применить атрибуты (например префикс) к нескольким роутам. Если заглянуть в код (вам может понадобиться IDE, чтобы не страдать изучая код Laravel), то ваш колбэк называется `$routes` (список маршрутов) и вызывается в `\Illuminate\Routing\Router` так: `$routes($this);`. Итог: Laravel и не должен передавать в этот колбэк параметр language.

Тогда как же работать с префиксами? В документации нет подходящего примера для префикса, но есть для поддомена:

```
Route::domain('{account}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

`$account` появился в обработчике роута из `{account}`. Вариант с префиксом мог бы быть таким:

```
Route::prefix('{language}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($language) {
        //
    });
});
```

Важно понимать, что параметры типа `{language}` извлекаются из запроса, а не из вашего массива. Если вы хотите ограничить возможные варианты маршрутов, то смотрите как это сделать в документации (например можно ограничить возможные значения параметра [регуляркой](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)).

Чтобы применить для всех маршрутов общий обработчик, в котором устанавливается локаль, вам понадобится [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware). Постарайтесь понять их [концепцию](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware).

Comment: Сейчас подумал, что вы, скорее всего, не хотите получать language в обработчике роута, тогда можно самостоятельно распарсить запрос (извлечь локаль  из пути) в мидлваре.